# Place one div under another div in this code sample

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with [this code on codepen](https://codepen.io/badpixel/pen/GqNPzK) and I am trying to place text, under the animated circle and centered in the viewport, but I cannot seem to find a way to do it. I have set `background: yellow;` on the text for visibility.

If you know why the solution works, it would be immensely helpful if you could explain it here for me to understand/learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use flex, then apply it on HTML so body can shrink on content. `margin-left:-50%;` will be efficient and can be used to center one element.

For `vertical-align`, you may use *(either)* `display :` `inline-block`/`inline-table` + `vertical-align:middle` in order to center 2 elements being side by sides.

basicly, your CSS template can become

```
html {
    height: 90%;
    background: #c2c2c2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

body {margin:0;}

.text {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-table;/* or inline-block to vertical align */
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -50%;/* body flex-child takes width of content, not window ;) */
    position: relative;/* bring it up front , add z-index too if needed */
}

.spinner {
    display: inline-block;/* not a flex-child anymore & float doesn't allow vertical-align */
    vertical-align: middle;/* says itself */
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
}
```

... and render -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNrxPQ
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Thank you for this, so in this case I could use `top:` to bring the text under the circle correct?

Comment: @badpixel what do you mean ? text outside and below the circle ?  top works for positionned(relative,absolute or fixed) elements here, here it is not (static is default) **edit:** *if this is what you looked for, then let it be a block* : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzpVor

Comment: In addition, why does the whole circle and text move to the left when the text is a sentence? How can this be stopped?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i mean, thank you. Regarding my previous comment, If you look at the code link in the original question you will be able to see that everything is shifted to the left.

Comment: It is shifted to left because text increase width of body (green bg ) https://codepen.io/badpixel/pen/GqNPzK :  if you reset to block and margin:auto, it works much better in this case : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWZBYb (body bg is tomato)  Each methods introduce different behaviors : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqWzdg

Comment: @badpixel  forgot to fork example with green background on body :) link is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLZmMO and not your initial pen https://codepen.io/badpixel/pen/GqNPzK

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I learned a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://codepen.io/Lansana/pen/ezvVYR

HTML:

```
<div class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div class='spinner'>
                <div class='quadrant'></div>
                <div class='quadrant'></div>
                <div class='quadrant'></div>
                <div class='quadrant'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='text'>test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 90%;
}

body {
  background: #c2c2c2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

.spinner-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
  //border-radius: 300px;

.quadrant {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    //z-index: 10;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    //opacity: .5;
    &:after {
      content: "";
      color: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation: slide_horiz_neg 12s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        //mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: cyan;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation: slide_vert_neg 8s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        //mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: yellow;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation: slide_horiz_pos 10s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        //mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: magenta;
      }
    }
   /* &:nth-child(4) {
     // animation: slide_vert_pos 3.5s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        mix-blend-mode: normal;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: #000000;
      }
    } */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_vert_pos {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(1%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_vert_neg {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_horiz_pos {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(1%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_horiz_neg {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1%);
  }
}
```

I created a wrapper, which contains your spinner and the text.

The wrapper has an auto height/width, based on it's child elements.

The text can be positioned any way you want within that wrapper, and it is not effected at all by the spinner except for the order in which the two are placed within the dom.

Comment: Answers placed on third-party sites does no future visitor any good should that site disappear or get edited tomorrow. You are required to place any code for your answer here.

Comment: Thanks, made updates.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code you can have look at codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMWZOM

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='spinner'>
            <div class='quadrant'></div>
            <div class='quadrant'></div>
            <div class='quadrant'></div>
            <div class='quadrant'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='text'>test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 90%;
}

.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

body {
  background: #c2c2c2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    background: yellow;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

.spinner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
  //border-radius: 300px;

.quadrant {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    //z-index: 10;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    //opacity: .5;
    &:after {
      content: "";
      color: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation: slide_horiz_neg 12s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        //mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: cyan;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation: slide_vert_neg 8s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        //mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: yellow;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation: slide_horiz_pos 10s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        //mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: magenta;
      }
    }
   /* &:nth-child(4) {
     // animation: slide_vert_pos 3.5s linear alternate infinite;
      &:after {
        mix-blend-mode: normal;
        //opacity: .5;
        background: #000000;
      }
    } */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_vert_pos {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(1%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_vert_neg {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_horiz_pos {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(1%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide_horiz_neg {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
.text {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  right: 150px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

Since your spinner's circumference was 300px, to center it directly below, I divided it by half and assigned that position to the text to center it as well as any number above 150px in order to settle below the circle. Remember, these positions act inverted. Right moves it left and so on.